# using typeof to find and Enum class by its name in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm looking for a way to implement such code:

```
public enum Enum1
{
    a=0,b
}

string enumName="Enum1";

Enum[] myEnum = (Enum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumName));
```

I want to get a set of enums by their name; but the "typeof" part won't work. please help.

Comment: You need a type then use Type.GetType(enumName). Don't forget to prepend namespace (typeof(Enum1).Namespace)

Answer (score 4):

`typeof` is a compile-time operator that would obviously work only for types that are known at compile-time.

If you need to load a certain type using a `string`, you can use the `Type.GetType()` method instead:

```
Enum[] myEnum = (Enum[])Enum.GetValues(Type.GetType(enumName));
```

Keep in mind, though, that you'll typically require the full namespace, not just the class name. For example: `"MyNamespace.Enums.Enum1"`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)